Thermal management
My goal is to maintain the temperature of an enclosure (1 m x 0.5 m x 0.25 m) at 35 °C, knowing that the outside temperature is around 23 °C. For regulation, I am hesitating between an electronic PID controller and an algorithm developed in a microcontroller. For thermal management, I am torn between a thermoelectric module and a PTC heating module with a fan. Are there any other more efficient and economical alternatives?

We need more information.  What is the heat load inside the enclosure?  What is the ambient environment - indoors / outdoors / sun / shade / rain - ?  What is the enclosure material?  How much power is available for the thermal system?  This gets into heater and fan sizes.

We are going to have to see a lot more details than just what you listed to do any kind of thermal engineering you have to know what your r value is. In addition you open this question twice please edit your old question don't open new questions they will be marked as duplicates

A Peltier cell has really low efficiency and is only effective on the contact surface (like and IC thermally bonded on it). Regarding the control there is no difference between buying a PID or developing yourself the algorithm on a microcontroller, it just depends on your knowledge and resources
